# Yii2 basic app loading Php dynamic library but advanced app not loading on the same server. Why?

Tags: php, apache, yii2, yii2-advanced-app, yii2-basic-app

I have a shared web hosting server and running a yii2 basic app for long time without any issue.
Now i have developed a new Yii2 Advanced App which works good in localhost (WAMP).

When I uploaded the new app to the same server I got the following error:

```
PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library
'/usr/local/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20121212/ffmpeg.so' -
/usr/local/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20121212/ffmpeg.so:
cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

Basic App is working well and Advanced App has the above issues on the same server. What cause the above error? How to fix it?

Thanks.

Comment: What are your php versions on server and local machine? Show what modules are loaded on php `grep -Hrv ";" /etc/php5 | grep -E "extension(\s+)?="`. Try to disable modules which causing problems

Comment: This problem is due to some server setting . I wrote to the hosting provider and they fixed it immediately.  Thanks